# Regular Expression Match And Compare Captured Groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match some strings of the pattern:

```
event = sometext1 name = prefix sometext2
```

I want to match all cases that `sometext1` and `sometext2` are different. How should I do it with regular expression? Thanks!

Comment: Well I tried patterns like 'event = "/(\w+) \1/" name = "/(\w+) \2/"', which doesn't give me anything. Also I looked up named captures, but didn't find much about comparing value

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: Sublime text or powershell. Trying to keep it simple though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
event += +(\w+) +name+ = +\w+ +((?!\1)\w+)\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ7tP7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use a backreference like this:

```
^event = ([^\s]+) name = prefix (?!\1).+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2dfopOPYJqY23RRl)

Comment: Thanks for the illustration!