# Regex to find a line with two capture groups that match the same regex but are still different

Tags: regex

I am trying to analyse my source code (written in C) for not corresponding timer variable comparisons/allocations. I have a rage of timers with different timebases (2-250 milliseconds). Every timer variable contains its granularity in milliseconds in its name (e.g. `timer10ms`) as well as every timer-photo and define (e.g. `fooTimer10ms`, `DOO_TIMEOUT_100MS`).

Here are some example lines:

```
fooTimer10ms = timer10ms;
baaTimer20ms = timer10ms;
if (DIFF_100MS(dooTimer10ms) >= DOO_TIMEOUT_100MS)
if (DIFF_100MS(dooTimer10ms) < DOO_TIMEOUT_100MS)
```

I want to match those line where the timebases are not corresponding (in this case the second, third and fourth line). So far I have this regex:

```
(\d{1,3}(?i)ms(?-i)).*[^\d](\d{1,3}(?i)ms(?-i))
```

that is capable of finding every line where there are two of those granularities. So instead of just line 2, 3 and 4 it matches all of them. The only idea I had to narrow it down is to add a negative lookbehind with a back-reference, like so:

```
(\d{1,3}(?i)ms(?-i)).*[^\d](\d{1,3}(?i)ms(?-i))(?<!\1)
```

but this is not allowed because a negative lookbehind has to have a fixed length.

I found these two questions ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889304/regular-expression-match-and-compare-captured-groups?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C86.2145), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49801715/can-use-regex-to-compare-two-captured-groups?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C77.0739)) but the fist does not have the restriction of having both capture groups being of the same kind and the second is looking for equal instances of the capture group.

If what I want can be achieved way easier, by using something else than regex, I would be happy to know. My mind is just stuck due to my believe that regex is capable of that and I am just not creative enough to use it properly.

Comment: Please stop posting potential solutions as comments.  This can lead to question abandonment.  There is no way to DV bad/incorrect/flawed comments.  The comment box's placeholder text says not to post answers as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to match the timer part followed by the digits and use a negative lookahead with a backreference to assert that it does not occur at the right.

For the example data, a bit specific pattern using a range from 2-250 might be:

```
.*?(timer(?:2[0-4]\d|250|1?\d\d|[2-9])ms)\b\S*[^\S\r\n]*[<>]?=[^\S\r\n]*\b(?!\S*\1)\S+
```

The pattern matches

- `.*?` Match any char except a newline, as least as possible (Non greedy)
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `timer` Match literally
  - `(?:2[0-4]\d|250|1?\d\d|[2-9])` Match a digit in the range of 2-250
  - `ms` Match literally
- `)\b` Close group and a word boundary
- `\S*[^\S\r\n]*` Match optional non whitespace chars and optional spaces without newlines
- `[<>]?=` Match an optional `<` or `>` and `=`
- `[^\S\r\n]*\b` Match optional whitespace chars without a newline and a word boundary
- `(?!\S*\1)` Negative lookahead, assert no occurrence of what is captured in group 1 in the value
- `\S+` Match 1+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZRz1D/1)

Or perhaps a broader pattern matching 1-3 digits and optional whitespace chars which might also match a newline:

```
.*?(timer\d{1,3}ms\b)\S*\s*[<>]?=\s*\b(?!.*\1)\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dmqs27/1)

Note that `{1-3}` should be `{1,3}` and could also match 999

Comment: the {1-3} was just a typo my bad i ment {1,3}, specificly it is 2, 10, 20, 100 and 250 but still {1-3} should be matching those good enough. Sadly I chose an example where every line had an "=" sign but the comparison could as well be just > insted if >= and that is where the second solution does not work other than that it does just fine. and the "timer" part of it is according to my triel and error not even needed.

Comment: @EN20 In that case you can use an alternation matching either `=` or `<=` `>=` `>` or `<` `.*?(timer\d{1,3}ms\b)\S*\s*(?:[<>]?=|[<>])\s*\b(?!.*\1)\S+` See https://regex101.com/r/p8hWRh/1

Comment: tried around a bit and got it to work is added case insensetivity for the `ms part, placed the = together with thesome more making `[-+&%*\/|!<>=^]` insted of `?` zero to one i chaged it to `{1,3}` since I don't know of anything longer than e.g. `>>=` bitween two variables in terms of comparisons/allocations making it: `.*?(\d{1,3}(?i)ms(?-i))\S*\s*[-+&%*\/|!<>=^]{1,3}\s*\b(?!.*\1)\S+`

Comment: that works but i wouel like it to have no need for the comparison/allocation deleimiter at all if that is somehow possible

Comment: @EN20 Perhaps matching non word characters in between would be ok `.*?(timer\d{1,3}ms\b)\W+(?!.*\1)\S+` https://regex101.com/r/buuSox/1

Comment: jep last one does the trick for any instance i can think of so far

Comment: well here i go again still did not work, startet from scratch now I am finaly happy: `(\d{1,3}(ms)|\d{1,3}(MS)|\d{1,3}(mS)|\d{1,3}(Ms))(?!.*?\1)(?=.*(ms|MS|Ms|mS))`

Comment: @EN20 You can shorten that pattern by using a single capturing group and using 2 character classes matching all variations of ms `(\d{1,3}[Mm][Ss])(?!.*?\1)(?=.*[Mm][Ss])` See https://regex101.com/r/k4Rrbp/1